# Access denied to Failover CSVFS

Tags: windows

I've been trying to troubleshoot an issue with a CSVFS on my failover cluser. It all started after updating my nodes (windows update). Not quite sure if that's the root cause since all other CSVFS are available.

Whenever I try to access the volume from windows explorer I get an "access denied". However, I can access the content using cmd.

I've tried unexporting and exporting back in vain.
I also used icals to reset the permissions but no luck.

Can anyone provide me with a solution ?

I'm using an HP3PAR system. Volumes are exported using iSCSI.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset persistent reservation state. It may get stuck due to the firmware bug or whatever.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/clear-clusterdiskreservation?view=windowsserver2019-ps

If it won't help delete your CVS and re-create it from the scratch adding shared LUN to your cluster nodes one-by-one, you won't lose any data.